# creating a list of a combination of a variable times itself using a for loop R

Tags: r

```
Year=c(1936, 1946, 1951, 1963, 1975, 1997, 2006)
decform <- function(var){
mat <- matrix(nrow=21,ncol=2)
n<-1
m<-2
 for (i in var[(1:(length(var)-1))]){
   for (j in var[(m:(length(var)))]){
     mat[n,] <- c(i,j)
    }
      m <- m+1
      n <- n+1

  }
return(mat)
}


decform(Year)
```

Here is my R code for creating a 2 column matrix with 21 rows that corresponds to the number of possible combinations without repeating that could be done but the output is not right. Is there something wrong? With the code I need to use two nested for loops to accomplish this.

Comment: just use `combn`: `t(combn(Year, 2))`

Comment: I have to use two nested for loops. Wish it was that easy.

Comment: what do you need exactly. What is the output you arelooking for?

Comment: [,1] [,2]
 [1,] 1936 1946
 [2,] 1936 1951
 [3,] 1936 1963
 [4,] 1936 1975
 [5,] 1936 1997
 [6,] 1936 2006
 [7,] 1946 1951
 [8,] 1946 1963
 [9,] 1946 1975
[10,] 1946 1997
[11,] 1946 2006
[12,] 1951 1963
[13,] 1951 1975
[14,] 1951 1997
[15,] 1951 2006
[16,] 1963 1975
[17,] 1963 1997
[18,] 1963 2006
[19,] 1975 1997
[20,] 1975 2006
[21,] 1997 2006

Comment: A matrix that has 2 columns and 21 rows that replicates each year 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 times and shows the combination of each year without repeating. basically exactly what t(combn(Year,2)) outputs except using nested for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is very close, you just need to move the row iterator (in my example it's `p`, in your example it's `n`) to the second loop, instead of the first loop:

```
Year <- c(1936, 1946, 1951, 1963, 1975, 1997, 2006)
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 21, ncol = 2)

p <- 1 # row iterator
q <- 2 # second column iterator

for(i in 1:(length(Year) - 1)){ # first loop 

  for(j in q:length(Year)){ # second (nested loop)

    mat[p,] <- c(Year[i], Year[j])
    p <- p + 1 # iterate rows

  }

  q <- q + 1 # iterate second column

}

mat
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 1936 1946
# [2,] 1936 1951
# [3,] 1936 1963
# [4,] 1936 1975
# [5,] 1936 1997
# ....
```

Comment: ah, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Diver1 if my answer solved your problem, you may consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)